# Which is better: Inbound links to a single site or spread over multiple sites?

Tags: seo, domains

If I have 1000 external links with 50 distinct keywords, is it better to direct them all at one site or 10 different sites?  The numbers are just examples.

Comment: what is your goal?

Comment: To rank better for those 50 keywords.

Comment: it is not a straight answer, but it is my opinion and google's too: direct the links so it will be useful to your users and it will be also the best for SEO purposes for the long term.

Answer (score 3):

I did something very similar to improve my SEO and it worked; I faced the same question as you're asking and my answer was to do something like:

1000 sites pushed to 30 sites.
Those 30 sites pushed to 10 sites.
Those 10 sites pushed to my main site.

Please note, the example I gave shows only '3' stages, in live there were about 10.

Actually, on another site, I did it again and this method worked even better:

1000 sites pushed to 30 sites.
Those 30 sites pushed to 10 sites.
Those 10 sites pushed to **NOT** my main site but an 'information' site. 
My Information site and my main site shared a link.

The reason for this approach was my head saying the logic makes more sense. The reason why we link to a site is 2 fold. 
1) SEO
2) We are implying that the site being linked to (destination) is the Authority. The linking site (source) is just a reference. Hence why linking like this is popular.

However, it doesn't make total sense that the Authority is the more appropriate site. Think about cars. I could have a site about cars which links to a site which lists car manufacturers. OK, the car manufacturing site is the authority, but, if I wanted to know about cars then it's actually only painting part of the picture. Going back to the car site (the source) also has a link to another authority website about how the engine works, road traffic signs etc... Well, my site is never the authority but, it's actually the most *useful* website as from here, I can get to what I need. Ironically, my site which only has outbound links has become the authority.

This means you have to be careful about the linking to a destination page as it doesn't mean Google will view it as the most important and ironically I have had some of my 'child' sites rank better than my main site.

So, what is better? As time goes on, I think my car example site will become more prevalent with Google but for the moment, linking many to a few, then a few, then to one is a better approach. It also gives you scope to build on your child sites as they become popular, plus, you can also 'swamp' Google (although again, I advise doing this very cautiously).

Generally this is a 'grey hat' approach (and some may even describe as black hat) and should be done carefully.